# How to create dynamic UI?

Tags: user-interface, windows-mobile, mobile-phones, portability

Recently, I got a application to build for various mobile phones. Basically the Windows Mobile 6.x phones.
After thinking a little a bit about the application I stuck at one place. How one can build a portable application that work with different resolution and different screen size phones. So that UI is visible correctly on all the phones. Is there any tool or library avialable in the market? Or How do you do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use direct screen access (drawing geometric figures and pictures yourself), native Symbian OS C++ controls (buttons, lists...) or a combination of both? What versions of Symbian OS (or Series60 or UIQ) are you targetting?

Comment: Actually I am developing an application for windows mobile 6.0. And there many running with this OS with different screen size and resolution. UI is simple but the problem is due to varying size and resolution. So I was tryting to build this UI dyanamic so that it can work on most of the phone running WM6. So I was asking is there any UI toolkit which provides this facility, or is there any other way?

Comment: Alright. Editing the question so the Windows Mobile crowd can see it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing .NET WinForms, a couple ideas come to mind:

1) Create your UI such that all the controls use some sort of docking, that way they will stretch to fill any orientation/resolutions.   Then make sure you test with the different emulators and see how the UI looks on different resolutions.   Tweak as necessary.

2) Do #1, but also add in some manual sizing code in the Form.Activated and Form.Resized events.

Comment: +1 for docking, all the way.  Think through how you'd like each control to behave, and try to use the dock / anchor constructs to describe that.  Play with controls on a standard desktop form, then drag-resize and see how they react.  Most forms can be made to look "pretty good" (if not perfect) simply using default resize behavior.  Remember to use Panels if you need to "group" fixed-size elements together!

Answer (score 0):

Make-up your mind and then rephrase the question. If it is Symbian/S60 that you are targeting then open SDK's documentation (or Library section on Forum Nokia) and search for "scalable ui"

If you target both Symbian/S60 and WM then the answer to your question is Qt ( http://qt.nokia.com ).

Comment: J2ME could work better than Qt, depending on what you want your application to do.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful code in my case, to determine the width of UI element:

```
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
d.Size = gr.MeasureString("@@/@@/@@", d.Font).ToSize();
```

where d is control